# Dynamically re-order columns and set column width in an SSRS tablix

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

We have a grid on our application that we need to render as part of a report that will be rendered in SSRS.  The user has the ability to change the order and sizes of the columns in this grid in the application.

I now have the requirement to make the printed grid match the column order / column sizes at the time the report is rendered.

At the moment, this grid is rendered into a Tablix on the report.  I have tried using a parameter / expression to set the TablixColumn/Width but this does not apear to work.

Has anyone else encountered this requirement?  Any pointers to a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can delete the rdl as soon as you complete the rendering process. There is a method in webservice endpoint for deleting report from the server.

Comment: I have written a blog for this : [http://pldineshtech.blogspot.com/2011/03/dynamically-re-order-columns-in-sql.html](http://pldineshtech.blogspot.com/2011/03/dynamically-re-order-columns-in-sql.html) incase, you are interested :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have found your answer, but we are doing something similar. You'll read the report, get the RDL's XML file, navigate to the section where you have Tablix, TablixColumns etc., and then use XML classes to re-order columns, write the report back to Report server then render the report. I am looking for a simpler alternative, but haven't found it yet. Let me know if anyone have any suggestions. :)

Comment: We considered creating dynamic rdl and then writing the report back to the server so we could use the report viewer and then running a job to do a cleanup once a month but in the end we decided to use rdlc to create a PDF in this case.